# Regex directory renaming

Tags: ubuntu, regex, batch-rename

I'm not great with regex and can't figure out why this is selecting the next character after the -

```
/[\-][^ - ]/g
```

with that, it selects - and the following character.

I want to select the dash between two numbers, but don't want to select any dashes that have a space before and after.

in reality I'm trying to use this in ubuntu to recursively rename directories that are named

```
#### - ##-##
```

to

```
#### - ##:##
```

Comment: Can you add what it's currently matching? I'm having difficulty understanding what it's current behavior is and why it's incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Usually one would transform patterns like that by anchoring the dash against the digits which surround it, e.g.,

```
foo="123 - 456-78"
bar=$(echo "$foo" | sed -r -e 's,([[:digit:]])-([[:digit:]]),\1:\2,')
```

That is, matching a digit on each side and using a back reference to put the digits back.

Actually `sed` is not itself a good example, since this is (like `bash`) a use of EREs (extended regular expressions), and not [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).  However, since this is for Ubuntu, we can assume you are using [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-regexps), which has a `-r` option for specifying EREs.